# How to fix the definition(SQL) of a view that has errors (in ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, database, oracle-dbms

Occasionally, schema changes that are made in my tables cause errors in my views. Example: a field is changed in a table that was referenced by a view.

When there are errors in a view, ArcGIS Desktop throws errors:

- When the view is dragged to ArcMap, error: 'Could not add the specified data object to the map. DBMS table not found [ORA-24372: invalid object for describe]'
- When double clicked in Catalog, error: 'Failed to edit the selected object(s).'
- When right clicked >> Properties in Catalog: Nothing happens

I would like to either modify/fix the view's definition(SQL) or, at the very least, get the SQL, and then delete the broken VIEW and recreate it with working SQL. However, because there are errors, ArcGIS is not letting me get to the view's properties or the view's definition tab, to get at the SQL.

**How can I fix the definition(SQL) of a view that has errors in ArcGIS Desktop?**

Environment:

- ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1
- SDE 10.3.1
- Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0)

I do not have access to SQL Plus. I only have ArcGIS Desktop and MS Access, and do not have DBA privileges.

Comment: Best practice is to define views in scripts which can be re-run at need. If tables are changed, the script would then need to be altered  and re-run.  Not having  a native SQL client for database administration is a major flaw (especially considering the SQL-Plus addition is such a trivial addition to an Instant Client deployment (which isn't a registry item)), but `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute` can run SQL scripts if you parse them correctly.  Please edit your question to specify the exact release of Oracle, since "11g" is *two* families of releases.

Comment: If you cannot update the view definitions in Oracle perhaps you can use query layers instead of views? You can use the view definition logic in the Create Query Layer dialog to create and store query layers which should behave much as views do.

Comment: You may not have access to sqlplus but you surely have someone (à DBA) looking after it. Ask him/her to fix the view.

Comment: @Vince 1) Your suggestion of using scripts to create views is a good one. Will do. 2) Yes, you're right. I need SQL-Plus. I am also looking into arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute. 3) The Oracle version in the qeustion has been updated. Your comments were extremely helpful - thanks.

Comment: @Dowlers You're right, Query Layers would work in a pinch, but I'm really trying to stick with database views right now.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Yes, I'll ask the DBA to help if it comes to that. I'm hoping to solve this myself on my end if at all possible though.

Comment: @Vince You said this in a comment (back in 2016): `Best practice is to define views in scripts which can be re-run at need. If tables are changed, the script would then need to be altered and re-run.` At the time, I thought by 'script' you meant a geo-processing python script (cause that's how my GIS mind works). Now I realize that `.sql` scripts can be used for this purpose. Is this what you meant?

Comment: The emphasis on 'script' was in comparison to manual changes to existing tables. I've written a Python script that runs scripted SQL code (which I suffixed `.sqlr` since the Python did runtime replacement on cascading SQL statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to [query the view definition](http://justgeeks.blogspot.ca/2008/01/get-definition-for-view-in-oracle.html) (using an [MS Access Pass-through Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Process-SQL-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42)) to get the SQL as text:

```
select TEXT from ALL_VIEWS where view_name = 'my_view'
```

Once I had retrieved the broken SQL, I deleted the view, and then recreated it using corrected SQL.

To avoid this situation in the future, I'll take Vince's suggestion:

> Best practice is to define views in scripts which can be re-run at need. If tables are changed, the script would then need to be altered and re-run.